# cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'configuration'

Tags: xml, logback

I want to use Logback in my Web Project,but in logback.xml there is a problem:

> cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'configuration'.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="USER_HOME" value="logs" />
    <property scope="context" name="FILE_NAME" value="mylog-logback" />

    <timestamp key="byDay" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="file"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${USER_HOME}/${FILE_NAME}.log</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${USER_HOME}/${byDay}/${FILE_NAME}-${byDay}-%i.log.zip
            </fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>

    </appender>

    <logger name="com.linkcos.object.*" level="track" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
        <!-- <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" /> -->
    </logger>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

This is really a strange question,please help me!

Comment: I have found some solutions,but there is no use.[link](https://blog.giantgeek.com/?p=1129)

Comment: Well, this has no effect on my project, just the IDE's validation of XML

Comment: Hi, I am also getting same issue,  no idea how to resolve. How did you achieved solution ? Can you please tell ?

Answer (score 3):

Add `xmlns` and `xsi` in the `configuration` tag

```
<configuration
    xmlns="http://ch.qos.logback/xml/ns/logback"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://ch.qos.logback/xml/ns/logback http://ch.qos.logback/xml/ns/logback/logback.xsd">
```

Comment: Please elaborate on this answer to provide more value to the user (and to those who need this answer in the future).

Answer (score -2):

Do not import logback.xml to Spring Application.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit about how this approach works. Otherwise, I think it should be posted as a comment. Not an answer.