# Unable to skip the OncePerRequestFilter filter for a login url (basically to get the JWT token during the initial login)in spring boot security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am trying a develop a spring boot rest API with JWT authorization using spring security. I want all of my request to go through the filter to validate the JWT token  except for the `/authenticate` request which should generate the jwt token. But with the below code, the `/authenticate` request is also getting intercepted by the filter due to which its failing with 401. Please let me know what am I missing in the below code.

**JwtTokenFilter class**

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter
{

    @Autowired
    private UserService     jwtUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil    jwtTokenUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException
    {

        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        // JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get
        // only the Token
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer "))
        {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try
            {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            }
            catch (ExpiredJwtException e)
            {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
        }
        // Once we get the token validate it.
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null)
        {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            // if token is valid configure Spring Security to manually set
            // authentication
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails))
            {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                // After setting the Authentication in the context, we specify
                // that the current user is authenticated. So it passes the
                // Spring Security Configurations successfully.
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

**JwtConfig class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class JwtConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private UserService                 jwtUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenFilter              jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
        // user for matching credentials
        // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception
    {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception
    {
        // We don't need CSRF for this example

        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().
        // dont authenticate this particular request
                authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().
                // all other requests need to be authenticated
                anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
                // store user's state.
                exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterAfter(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

**Controller class**

```java
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class JwtAuthenticationController
{

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager   authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil            jwtTokenUtil;
    @Autowired
    private UserService             userDetailsService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody User authenticationRequest) throws Exception
    {
        authenticate(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());
        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
        final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

        User u = new User();
        u.setUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
        u.setToken(token);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(u);
    }
    private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
        }
        catch (DisabledException e)
        {
            throw new Exception("USER_DISABLED", e);
        }
        catch (BadCredentialsException e)
        {
            throw new Exception("INVALID_CREDENTIALS", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this for two days and the best solution was the [Tom answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52370780/12664985) combined with this setup on my `SecurityConfig`:

```
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity?) {
        // Disable CORS
        http!!.cors().disable()

        // Disable CSRF
        http.csrf().disable()

        // Set session management to stateless
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

        //Add JwtTokenFilter
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, OncePerRequestFilter works in that way only. Not sure if this can be avoided. Quoting the documentation :

> Filter base class that aims to guarantee a single execution per
>   request dispatch, on any servlet container.

You can try adding the method type as well to skip teh authentication on the endpoint.
`.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,  "/authenticate").permitAll()`

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed by Mohit, even i couldn't see any mistakes in your configuration.

If you understand below explanation, it will help you to resolve.
Even though `/authenticate` request is permitAll configured the request should pass through your JWT Filter. But `FilterSecurityInterceptor` is the last filter it will check for configured antMatchers and associated restrictions/permissions based on that it will decide whether request should be permitted or denied.

For `/authenticate` method it should pass through filter and requestTokenHeader, username should be null and make sure `chain.doFilter(request, response);` is reaching without any exceptions.

And when it reaches `FilterSecurityInterceptor` and If you have set log level to debug) logs similar as given below should be printed.

```
DEBUG - /app/admin/app-config at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor' 
DEBUG - Checking match of request : '/app/admin/app-config'; against '/resources/**' 
DEBUG - Checking match of request : '/app/admin/app-config'; against '/' 
DEBUG - Checking match of request : '/app/admin/app-config'; against '/login' 
DEBUG - Checking match of request : '/app/admin/app-config'; against '/api/**' 
DEBUG - Checking match of request : '/app/admin/app-config'; against '/app/admin/app-config' 
DEBUG - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /app/admin/app-config; Attributes: [permitAll] 
DEBUG - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@511cd205: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@2cd90: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 696171A944493ACA1A0F7D560D93D42B; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS 
DEBUG - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@6df827bf, returned: 1 
DEBUG - Authorization successful
```

Attach those logs, so that then problem can be predicted.

Comment: I have explained in this answer(in given link) how to set logger level to debug and printing the logs to Eclipse/STS console. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57895752/2825798

Comment: @Archana Make sure there is no typo error in your request URL. It should be `/authenticate` and if your request URL varies like `/authentcate` or `/authanticate` or any typo will results in 401 because requested URL is different than permitted URL. Just a possibility. Just check it.

Comment: @ PraveenKumar  ,I am getting error " Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 16; Element type "configuration" must be declared "  after adding the logback.xml.Below is my logback.xml and my eclipse version is Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0).Tried out few solutions from post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745105/cvc-elt-1-cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-configuration) , but didnt work.

Comment: I also tried overriding this method to skip filter for /authenticate, but its failing with 403 after adding below snippet                                                       `@Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
  System.out.println(request.getServletPath());
        return new AntPathMatcher().match("/authenticate", request.getServletPath());
    }`

Comment: @ArchanaAcharyaT As you mentioned spring-boot in question tag. I think spring boot have dependency of logback by default. Have you added dependency of logback? Try adding this ```<dependency>
   <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
   <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.3</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>```

Comment: If that didn't work you can try out log4j way of setting logger level to DEBUG in spring-mvc/spring-security. (I have not used log4j.xml used only logback) Try to modify log4j.xml and set root logger level to DEBUG

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to mention that I was running the application in wildfly server and not on embedded tomcat.After enabling the debug logs in server , I could see the authorization successfull in logs and later the request even reached the controller but exception was getting thrown in my controller as I am using BCryptPasswordEncoder and the password in my db was not matching with one in request. Below is the logs *16:40:45,989 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor] (default task-1) Authorization successful* .

Comment: ,Thanks for the help as I understood the flow and the issue after reading the debug logs.

Answer (score 0):

Write a configuration class that implements *org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter* and override the configur method like so:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    // dont authenticate this particular request. you can use a wild card here. e.g /unprotected/**
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().
            //authenticate everything else
    anyRequest().authenticated().and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, and I overcome it by comparing request path to the path I do not want to filter.

```
@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        //To skip OncePerRequestFilter for authenticate endpoint
        if(request.getServletPath().equals("/authenticate")){
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

// filter logic continue..
```