# How to skip oncePerRequest filter when using httpservletRequest.login()

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to login using httpServletRequest.login(), after registration for automatic login. BUT when I do this, I hit the OncePerRequest.doFilterInternal which checks the headers for an authorization header and kicks me out.

I dont think I am supposed to hit this for login, right now when I hit the route "api/v1/auth/login" I never hit the filter OncePerRequest.doFilterInternal. And its 200 response includes authorization jwt token as expected.

Am I not using the OncePerRequest.doFilterInternal correctly? I want to be able to login and set an authorization header in the response when a user registers.

Relevant code:

```
public class JwtTokenVerifier extends OncePerRequestFilter {
private final SecretKey secretKey;
private final JwtConfig jwtConfig;

public JwtTokenVerifier(SecretKey secretKey,
                        JwtConfig jwtConfig) {
    this.secretKey = secretKey;
    this.jwtConfig = jwtConfig;
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response,
                                FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(jwtConfig.getAuthorizationHeader());

    if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(authorizationHeader) || !authorizationHeader.startsWith(jwtConfig.getTokenPrefix())) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
    String token = authorizationHeader.replace(jwtConfig.getTokenPrefix(), "");

    try {

        Jws<Claims> claimsJws = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(secretKey)
                .parseClaimsJws(token);
        Claims body = claimsJws.getBody();

        String username = body.getSubject();
        var authorities = (List<Map<String, String>>) body.get("authorities");

        Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> simpleGrantedAuthorities = authorities.stream()
                .map(m -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(m.get("authority")))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                username,
                null,
                simpleGrantedAuthorities
        );

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    } catch (JwtException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Token %s cannot be trusted:", token));
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends 
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private final AuthUserServiceImpl authUserServiceImpl;
private final IUserRepository iUserRepository;
private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
private final SecretKey secretKey;
private final JwtConfig jwtConfig;
private final AccessDeniedFilter accessDeniedFilter;
private final AuthenticationEntryPointFilter authenticationEntryPointFilter;

@Autowired
public ApplicationSecurityConfig(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
                                 AuthUserServiceImpl authUserServiceImpl,
                                 SecretKey secretKey,
                                 JwtConfig jwtConfig,
                                 AccessDeniedFilter accessDeniedFilter,
                                 AuthenticationEntryPointFilter authenticationEntryPointFilter,
                                 IUserRepository iUserRepository) {
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    this.authUserServiceImpl = authUserServiceImpl;
    this.secretKey = secretKey;
    this.jwtConfig = jwtConfig;
    this.accessDeniedFilter = accessDeniedFilter;
    this.authenticationEntryPointFilter = authenticationEntryPointFilter;
    this.iUserRepository = iUserRepository;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "index", "/css/*", "/js/*", "/api/v1/auth/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAnyRole(ADMIN.name(), USER.name())
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedFilter)
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPointFilter)
                .and()
            .addFilter(jwtAuthorizationFilter())
            .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenVerifier(secretKey, jwtConfig), JwtUsernameAndPasswordJwtFilter.class);
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("whatever.com));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "access-control-allow-origin"));
    configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(authUserServiceImpl);
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    return provider;
}

public JwtUsernameAndPasswordJwtFilter jwtAuthorizationFilter() throws Exception {
    JwtUsernameAndPasswordJwtFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter = new JwtUsernameAndPasswordJwtFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtConfig, secretKey, iUserRepository);
    jwtAuthenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/v1/auth/login");
    return jwtAuthenticationFilter;
}
```

}

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public ResponseEntity<?> registerUserAccount(
        @Valid @RequestBody AuthUserRequest authUserRequest,
        Errors errors) throws NullPointerException {
        String password = authUserRequest.getPassword();
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errors.getFieldError());
        }
        try {
            iAuthUser.registerNewUserAccount(authUserRequest);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }

    try {
        httpServletRequest.login(authUserRequest.getUsername(), password);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        System.out.println("Servlet Error: " + e);
    }

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I intended to say I do not hit the filter 'JwtTokenVerifier extends OncePerRequest' when I hit the route `api/v1/auth/login`. There is no api/v1/login. And this is confirmed by Logging.


Question is updated with controller where I am calling httpServletRequest.login after register success.

Comment: I have used breakpoint and Logging.

Comment: For what it's worth, I believe the reason i am skipping OncePerRequestFilter is from the method 'jwtAuthenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/v1/auth/login");' In the config.
[here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html#setFilterProcessesUrl-java.lang.String-)

Comment: You are right. I am talking about JwtTokenVerifier. And by no means am certain. But I believe that line is the culprit because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58938733/unable-to-skip-the-onceperrequestfilter-filter-for-a-login-url-basically-to-get) and because that line is the only line in the codebase that addresses that route specifically.